# DPAPI encrypt in C++ app, decrypt in C# app

Tags: windows, dpapi

I want to encrypt data in C++ based application, store it in file, and then decrypt it in other C# application. Could I use corresponding DPAPI parts?

Is it possible to protect data in C++ application using `CryptProtectData()`, write it into file, and later read this file from other C# based application and decrypt using `ProtectedData` `Unprotect()` method?

Is there are a better way to share data between C++ and C# application in secure for usual user (not absolutely secure sure) way.

Comment: Can't see why not. At the end of the day the .net version is calling the same library as the C++ version. Beware of impersonation and delegation. However, if you are just trying to pass data back and forth from C++/C# there are better ways.

Comment: @Aron I need this data(in fact it is simple database) to be quite, but not absolutely hard to be modified, for usual user. Anyway could you represent the better way for me? I will modify my question.

Comment: In that case I would advise against your current tack. DPAPI is for securing data using an account. I would use SQL Server authorization instead. The general advice for any developers trying to implement their own security is DON'T.

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely do this, but if you're looking for better ideas, it would be helpful to understand what kind of data you're sharing between the C++ and C# apps.